# How can you access nested classes

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, nested

If I have something along the following lines

```
namespace mynamespace
{
  class A
  {
    public:
    class B{};
    class C{};
  };
int foo(B bObject, C cObject); //error
}
```

When compiled, B and C do not name types. Is there a way so that I can define functions in the namespace that use public nested classes (B and C) defined in Class  A?

Answer (score 8):

Use the scope resolution operator. `B` and `C` are declared in the scope of class `A`.

```
int foo(A::B bObject, A::C cObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, such a simple solution!